# 'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I used a very simple animation that opens a button bar in a very soft an smooth way:

```
.animation(.spring(response:1.5))
```

I want to update my app to iOS15 and 'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0

So I tried to change my animation to:

```
.animation(.spring(response:1.5), value: 0)
```

or something like:

```
 .animation(.spring(response: 1.5, dampingFraction: 2.5, blendDuration: 2.5), value: 10)
```

however, the new animation pops up very fast and the smooth effect is gone.

Does anyone know how to bring my little spring animation to iOS 15?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When using the `animation` modifier with `value`, the animation *only* runs *when* the `value` **changes**.

So for example, if the animation should be triggered when a boolean value is toggled, you would do the following:

```
@State private var showThing = false

/* ... */

.animation(.spring(response: 1.5), value: showThing)
```

When running `showThing.toggle()`, you will see this animation take affect.

Documentation for [`animation(_:value:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/animation(_:value:)):

> Applies the given animation to this view when the specified value changes.

> A view that applies `animation` to this view whenever `value` changes.

> `value`: A value to monitor for changes.

Comment: Thank you. As I'm reading your answer I noticed how dumb my question was. Maybe it is a little bit to late and I'll better go to bed :-)

Comment: @Michael It's not dumb at all, and it's sure to help someone in the future too! I'd be lying if I didn't initially think what you did is how it worked :p

Comment: Thank you :-) I've thought value has to be a Double...

Comment: @Michael The `value` is anything that conforms to `Equatable` (AKA it can be compared to see if it is/isn't equal). This means that if you can use `==` to check if the values are 'equivalent', it will work. `Double` can be used here, but using `Equatable` means it will work for many more types, including custom types (conforming to `Equatable`).